# APIM context.Response.Body always null

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-eventhub

I have an APIM policy to send a request and response to an Azure Event Hub:

```
    <outbound>
        <log-to-eventhub logger-id="my-logger">@{
            var request = context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
            var response = context.Response.Body?.As<string>(preserveContent: true);

            var json = new JObject(
                new JProperty("DateTimeStamp", DateTime.UtcNow),
                new JProperty("IpAddress",context.Request.IpAddress),
                new JProperty("RequestBody", request),
                new JProperty("ResponseBody", response),
                new JProperty("ResponseCode", context.Response.StatusCode)
            );
                
            return json.ToString();
        }</log-to-eventhub>
        <base />
    </outbound>
```

A request made via Postman or any other client shows the response has the correct body but in the code above context.Response.Body is always null, hence the null check. The message shows up in the event hub fine with a correct request message but null response.

There are other policies on the API but this is the only outbound policy. What could be causing this?

Edit with full Trace message taking out the null check and using JObject as suggested.

```
log-to-eventhub (0.405 ms)
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "message": "Expression evaluation failed.",
            "expression": "\n            var request = context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);\n            var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true);\n\n            var json = new JObject(\n                new JProperty(\"DateTimeStamp\", DateTime.UtcNow),\n                new JProperty(\"ServiceName\",context.Deployment.ServiceName),\n                new JProperty(\"RequestId\",context.RequestId),\n                new JProperty(\"IpAddress\",context.Request.IpAddress),\n                new JProperty(\"OperationName\",context.Operation.Name),\n                new JProperty(\"RequestBody\", request),\n                new JProperty(\"ResponseBody\", response.ToString()),\n                new JProperty(\"ResponseCode\", context.Response.StatusCode)\n            );\n                \n            return json.ToString();\n        ",
            "details": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        },
        "Expression evaluation failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you paste full policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In place of `As<string>` try using `As<JObject>` which would return json JObject.

```php
var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true);
```

> [JObject()](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject__ctor.htm) Initializes a new instance of the JObject class.

- for more information check https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried that but with so many changes I tried it again. The problem is that the Body object itself is null so we get an exception. Running a request via the portal and looking at the full Trace results shows this error:

"Expression evaluation failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @semprini Trying checking this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47931236) which has the solution for the error which you receive.

Comment: thanks again for the rapid response. It seems like a similar situation but that is pulling a variable from the variables array and preserving it, in this case I want the whole Body object. I'm already using one of the suggested solutions in that answer, which is to set preserveContent to true. Casting context.Response.Body.As<JObject> to IResponse still results in the same exception. In every piece of documentation or SO answer related to this I see people parsing Response.Body just fine. Something is setting it to null in this instance but I can't see why.

Comment: your SO link above eventually led me to the solution. It took a bit more digging but there was a backend policy interfering with the response. It would be great if APIM logging had a verbose option so we could see everything that was going on. Thanks again

Comment: @semprini If my answer resolved your issue could you please help me in accepting it so that it would be helpful for other community members.